# Get download file format and name in VC++

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, download, format

I am using Visual C++ to implement a function that could download image from a query. 

(**for example** `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false`)

Note that there's no image information associate with the query itself.

Now I can successfully download it, but I want to know if there is a way I can find the download image format (i.e. jpg or png, etc) and the image name?

Edit: if you try to save the image download from the above link, you can see the browser could automatically save it as `staticmap` and with extension `png`. I was wondering where the browser could get this information?

Comment: From the HTTP reply headers? Read [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the server is responding with the content type in the HTTP response headers:

```
Content-Type: image/png
```

This is the "Internet media type" or "MIME type" of the response content.